# Consuming Webservice - Sending Signature- Error X509Certificate2 type was not expected

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, web-services, xml-signature

I'm consume an external webservice for sending data, using a web application in asp.net and Visual Studio 2010. The

sending of data must be digitally signed using a digital signature. The webservice contains the Signature class, where I

can fill all required values ​​(SignedInfo, SignatureValue, KeyInfo).

I'm trying to fill the KeyInfo structure with the certificate like this:

```
    Dim Sig As New RSP.SignatureType

(...)
Sig.SignedInfo = Sig_info
(...)
Sig.SignatureValue = Sig_value


Dim rspKey_info As New RSP.KeyInfoType()
Dim rspX509 As New RSP.X509DataType()

Dim arrCertificate As X509Certificate2()
arrCertificate = myF.ReturnCertificateCC()

rspKey_info.ItemsElementName = New RSP.ItemsChoiceType2(0) {}
rspKey_info.ItemsElementName(0) = RSP.ItemsChoiceType2.X509Data
rspKey_info.Items = New Object(0) {}

rspX509.ItemsElementName = New RSP.ItemsChoiceType2(0) {}
rspX509.ItemsElementName(0) = RSP.ItemsChoiceType2.X509Data
rspX509.Items = New Object(0) {}
rspX509.Items(0) = arrCertificate (0)


    Sig.KeyInfo = rspKey_info

    xmlString = myF.SerializeAnObject(Sig)
```

When I try to serialize the Signature Object, an error occur:
"Error generating the XML document."

InnerException: 
"{ " The System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 type was not expected . Use XmlInclude or

SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically. "}"

```
    Public Function SerializeAnObject(ByVal obj As Object) As String

Dim doc As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
Dim serializer As System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer = New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())
Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()

        Try
            serializer.Serialize(stream, obj)
            stream.Position = 0
            doc.Load(stream)
            Return doc.InnerXml
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ""
        Finally
            stream.Close()
            stream.Dispose()
        End Try

        '#utilização  
        'dim xmlObject As string = SerializeAnObject(myClass)

    End Function
```

Please help me...
I'm at several days trying to solve this...

Thanks in advance!

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
rspX509.ItemsElementName = New RSP.ItemsChoiceType(0) {}
rspX509.ItemsElementName(0) = RSP.ItemsChoiceType.X509Certificate
rspX509.Items = New Object(0) {}
rspX509.Items(0) = arrCertificate (0)

rspKey_info.Items(0) = rspX509
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.